# issue with discontinued or missing journal

Tags: journals

I published a couple of papers for the International Journal of Security and Its Applications which was run by a publisher called SERSC (Science and Engineering Research Support Society). The link in Scimago is the following:
https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=21100199112&tip=sid

One of my papers was indexed in Scopus and the other one was indexed by ESCI. The reason for that is that in 2017, approximately, Scopus stopped indexing this journal.

The problem is that since November of this year the journal and the publisher links are not accessible; some authors also have claimed through Scimago that the emails of the editors are not actually working. The question that I have is what to do with the two articles that were published in that journal? Because it is no longer accessible, should I put it on my personal web page? Or just wait and see?

In general, what can an author do with their published works when the journal "disappears" eventually?

Comment: Was the journal printed on paper or electronic only?

Comment: only electronic, that was a problem also @AlexanderWoo

Comment: If I were in your situation, I'd probably put my paper on the web where people can access it. Of course, I'd be ready to take it down if the publisher told me to (assuming I had transferred the copyright to the publisher), but if I got such a request then that would probably also enable me to contact the publisher.

Comment: References:  https://www.lockss.org/ https://clockss.org/

Answer (score 6):

Publishers who care about the availability of published works tend to join archival initiatives such as the [Controlled Lots Of Copies Keeps Stuff Safe (CLOCKSS)](https://clockss.org/) or [Portico](https://www.portico.org/). These archives become public after so-called 'trigger events' occur (as determined by a governing body of these initiatives), such as when the articles are no longer available through the original publisher. This archival is a primary function of a scholarly communication system (see also [Roosendaal & Geurts, 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/20180223112609/http://www.physik.uni-oldenburg.de/conferences/crisp97/roosendaal.html))

If your publisher does not have this policy, you could rehost the article on your webpage or another file sharing site. Note that this would depend on the copyright status, because if the publisher (for example) went bankrupt the copyrights might be transferred in a firesale of that company.

Edit: Centralized => Controlled

Comment: I'd be very surprised if "Centralized" was part of the CLOCKSS acronym. Their FAQ ( https://clockss.org/faq/ ) says it's for "Controlled".